# Extract Source And Target Tables from Sql File Using Python Or any language

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to extract source and target tables from sql file using python. Till Now i am able to extract those using simple python code that looks for keywords "from, join, insert, create" to extract table names
But Now i am doing it for procedures which can contains functions and can be used after from which can come in my source list which i donot want. I tried to remove it but failed. I am pasting my code from which i was extracting my source and target

```py
def tables_in_query(sql_str):
    # remove the /* */ comments
    q = re.sub(r'/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^*/][^*]*\*+)*/', "", sql_str)

    # remove whole line -- and # comments
    lines = [line for line in q.splitlines() if not re.match("^\\s*(--|#)", line)]

    # remove trailing -- and # comments
    q = " ".join([re.split("--|#", line)[0] for line in lines])

    # split on blanks, parenthesis and semicolons
    tokens = re.split(r"[\s)(;]+", q)

    source, target, target_views, with_1 = set(), set(), set(), set()


    view_idx = [i+1 for i, x in enumerate(tokens) if x.lower() in ["view"]]
    for i in view_idx:
        target_views.add(tokens[i])

    with_index = [i + 1 for i, x in enumerate(tokens) if x.lower() in ["with"]]
    for i in with_index:
        t = tokens[i]
        if not (t.lower().startswith('tmp') or t.lower() in ["table", "replace"]):
            with_1.add(t)

    target_index = [i + 3 for i, x in enumerate(tokens) if x.lower() in ["create"]]
    for i in target_index:
        t = tokens[i]
        if not (t.lower().startswith('tmp') or t.lower() in ["table", "replace"]) and not with_1.__contains__(
                t.lower()):
            target.add(t)

    target_index = [i + 2 for i, x in enumerate(tokens) if x.lower() in ["insert"] and tokens[i+1].lower() in ["into"]]
    for i in target_index:
        t = tokens[i]
        if not (t.lower().startswith('tmp') or t.lower() in ["table", "replace"]) and not with_1.__contains__(
                t.lower()):
            target.add(t)


    target_idx = [i + 1 for i, x in enumerate(tokens) if x.lower() in ["update"]]
    for i in target_idx:
        t = tokens[i]
        if not (t.lower().startswith('tmp') or t.lower() in ["table", "replace"]) and not with_1.__contains__(
                t.lower()):
            target.add(t.replace('..', '.admin.'))

    source_index = [i + 1 for i, x in enumerate(tokens) if x.lower() in ["from", "join"]]
    for i in source_index:
        t = tokens[i]
        if not (t.lower().startswith('tmp') or t.lower() == "select" or t.lower() == "" or t.lower().startswith("substr") or t.lower().startswith("last_day")) and not with_1.__contains__(
                t.lower()):
            source.add(t)
            # print(t)

    source_idx = [i + 2 for i, x in enumerate(tokens) if x.lower() in ["alter"]]
    for i in source_idx:
        t = tokens[i]
        if not (t.lower().startswith('tmp') or t.lower() == "select" or t.lower() == "") and not with_1.__contains__(
                t.lower()):
            source.add(t)

    return source, target, target_views
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a lot of work to me. I suggest you use tried and tested solutions such as *sql-metadata* (https://github.com/macbre/sql-metadata) amd *sql-parse* (https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse)

Alternatively, if you're using SQLITE - and possibly other dbase engines - you may also try using EXPLAIN to obtain a table of bytecodes for your SQL statement of interest, then look for table opcodes such as OpenRead (source table), OpenWrite (target table) and DropTable (target table?). The table references are in the P2 column, which you can look up the SQLITE_MASTER table to obtain the table names. This has the advantage that if your SQL statement references a view, the bytecode will refer to the underlying tables instead, which no amount of parsing will reveal.

Comment: sql-metadata does not seperate tables into source and target. I want  my code to seprate both source and target tables

Comment: You are right, *sql-metdata* does not distinguish between source and target tables. But you can easily adapt the *sql-parse* parser to differentiate between them if you wish.